# Regex for Newbie

Tags: regex, scala

I'm new to regex and trying to figure something out for use in scala.

I'm trying to identify URLs within a very long string. I've looked around a lot and the best I've found is

```
val regex = """https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?""".r
```

That leaves a little something to be desired however leaving things like "">Images" at the end. I'm trying to figure out what the heck my regex means so I can dissect it and make it stop when it hits a non word character after the `.` in `.com`/`.org`/`.edu`/`.whatever`.

I was hoping someone wouldn't mind explaining what individual elements are within this pre-formed regex so that I may figure out what's going on and learn more about regex. I've gone through a tutorial or two and found out some things, but what I've asked for I think would be invaluable to me right now.

I get that:

- `?` after https means the s is optional
- `?` after elements mean they're optional
- `\w` seems to mean word characters
- `\d` seems to mean digits
- `.` cover most characters unless escaped

I don't get:

- how we're figuring out when to escape
- how `:` works or `+`
- what escape characters are really (I thought it was a backslash, but that doesn't seem to work here?)
- how to specify that a requirement can word for a range, so like word char isn't just one char, but 1-X chars

Anyways I was hoping someone could mentor me for a question rather than shove me to yet another tutorial by helping explain individual elements as they come up. I'd appreciate it.

`regexlib` was helpful and got me:

```
val regex = """https?://\w+\.\w+\.\w+[\w/_\.\?=&:]+""".r
```

every bit of which I understand!

Comment: http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Comment: http://regexpal.com/ Is a great tool for creating/learning regex. It has a full reference sheet and it selects the text in real time as you fill in the regex, so you can see exactly what's happening.

Comment: @phizzle those are javascript regexs, we're talking about java/scala regexs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your main problem with ">Images being included is solved by replacing the part matching the query html string

```
(\?\S+)
```

with something that does not include " < > as the \S does

```
(\?[\w=$&.\-^@#~+%]+)
```